# Excel VBA: How to add all of the current shapes on a worksheet to a ShapeRange?

Tags: excel, shapes, vba

Somewhat of a VBA newbie here.

It is clear to me how to create a `ShapeRange` using individual or multiple `Shape` objects:

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = MySht
'
'*Add some shapes*
'
Dim shprng As ShapeRange
Set shprng = sht.Shapes.Range(Array(1,2,3))
```

Is there a way to add ALL of the currently existing shapes on a worksheet to `shprng`? In other words, is there a method to return a `ShapeRange` from a `Shapes` object...? Something like this:

```
Set shprng = sht.Shapes.Range.SelectAll '<--- Does not work: Type Mismatch
Set shprng = sht.Shapes                 '<--- Same error
Set shprng = sht.Shapes.Range           '<--- Error: Argument not optional
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to create a ShapeRange by selecting all the shapes on a sheet, you would first select them then get the ShapeRange from the Selection object.

```
sht.Shapes.Range.SelectAll
Set shprng = Selection.ShapeRange
```

I usually prefer not to use the Selection object in VBA because it tends to be flaky and can cause errors in weird situations. I think a better way to do this is to build an array of Shape indexes and get the ShapeRange using this array.

```
Dim shape_index As Variant
Dim i As Long

ReDim shape_index(1 To sht.Shapes.Count)
For i = 1 To UBound(shape_index)
    shape_index(i) = i
Next

Set shprng = sht.Shapes.Range(shape_index)
```

Comment: Thanks- that accomplishes what I am trying to do. Do you happen to know if the `Shapes` collection object is an actively maintained object vector? What I mean by that is: say `sht.Shapes.Count = 5` and I were to do `sht.Shapes(2).Delete`; does `sht.Shapes.Count` now equal 4, and do `Shapes(3)` and `Shapes(4)` now become 2 and 3?

Comment: Yes, the Shapes object will automatically update as you describe.

Comment: side note: two shapes can have the same name , in wich case your code fails. bypass this by adding shapes to shprng  this way : `shprng.select : sht.Shapes(i).select replace:=false : set shprng = selection.shaperange` . Works if activesheet is the sheet where the shapes are.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I've updated the code to select by index which I dunno why I didn't do in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

In my Office 365, the code of TmDean did not work. It was necessary explicitly declare of variable as dinamic array.

```vb
    Dim shape_index() As Variant    'Dim shape_index() as Long
    Dim i As Long

    ReDim shape_index(1 To sht.Shapes.Count)
    For i = 1 To UBound(shape_index)
        shape_index(i) = i
    Next

    Set shprng = sht.Shapes.Range(shape_index)
```